# Recursive is_prime function in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, primes

In my school's Computer Science 2 class we are currently exploring recursion. We have already used recursion to do things like factorial or the Fibonacci sequence, but are stuck on an `is_prime(n)` function which returns True if n is prime, otherwise returning False. We wrote one iteratively previously, but can not seem to figure out how to do it recursively. This is what we have so far:

```
def is_prime(n):

    if n < 2: return False
    #1 or 0 is not prime, base case 1

    if n == 2 or n == 3: return True
    #2 and 3 are both prime, base case 2

    if is_prime(n-1): return False
    #This checks if n-1 is prime, b/c if so then n must not be prime
    #However, this only works b/c the first few numbers have lots of primes

    return True
    #Only returns True if nothing else has returned
```

If anyone could help us out a little, preferably through just a couple hints, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Well if `n-1` is prime and `n > 3` then `n` is composite. Other than that trivial observation, knowing what happens with `n-1` tells you very little about `n`. There is no nice way to reduce the problem of checking if `n` is a prime to that of checking if `n-1` is prime.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think this is a good candidate for recursion.  An iterative solution will be simpler and faster.  I realize you have no choice in the matter, but still, it seems like a silly assignment to me.

Comment: @TomKarzes I agree that it makes little sense in Python (or most languages) to do this, but there are languages like Lisp in which most computation is done recursively. A good Intro to Computer Science course should expose students to various paradigms, so it makes some sense as a learning exercise to figure out how to do something like this recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_prime(n-1)` is not terribly helpful in computing `is_prime(n)`. Instead, a recursive approach would have the recursion in a helper function which does the bulk of the computation.

Something like `no_divisors(n,k)` which evaluates to `True` if the range 2, 3, ..., `k` contains no divisors of `n`. It is easy to see that `no_divisors(n,k)` can be reduced to `no_divisors(n,k-1)`. Define this function, and then define `is_prime()` in terms of it. As an optimization you might want to first check for divisibility by 2 and 3 as basis cases and just look at odd candidate divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe recurse over another value instead and repeatedly check that your n is not a multiple of that value? Like so:

Start with d as the **upper bound**

1) if d has reached **lower bound** - return false

2) if n multiple of d - return true

3) default case - recurse by decremeting d

You get to choose what lower bound and upper bound mean. (e.g. from 2 to n/2 is the most basic approach)

Another possible lower-upper bound approach could be to recurse over d from sqrt(n) to 2 or even to check division by 2 before-hand and skip some values etc...

Answer (score 0):

A trivial way of determining primality is to test if `n % x == 0` for all integers x in the interval [2, sqrt(n)]. To do this recursively:

- start our `x` at 2
- check if `n % x == 0`
- if not, increment x and call the `is_prime` function again
- if `n < x * x` then `n` is prime